# How do I move a radiator about 15 centimetres?

Tags: radiator

I can remount the brackets no problem, but may have to extend the pipes on both sides. How do I do it, and how hard is it?

Comment: Up, down, left, right, out, in? Iron, copper, bronze, lead? You don't give us much to go on. Add some details, or a picture.

Comment: I can pretty well guarantee that you will not get an answer until you post a picture so we can see what you see. More than one, preferably from different angles.

Comment: You really do need to post a picture and declare which way you want to move it, what the pipes are made of - they are not all standard. By your use of the metric system - you are not in the USA .. specify locality so people can post things that are code specific to your region of the world.

Comment: Ok fair point, will do when I get a chance